# Get username from $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the username of my users to echo out but only seeing the userID or if I try to echo the username it gives me the string length rather than the actual name.

I am calling in my session script into my header which is included on all pages:

```
    <?
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['username']=$email;
 include ('../db_con.php');
?>
```

within the header.php file I want to echo out the username but not as mentioned above when I try that it show the length and not the actual name:

```
            <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; 
            var_dump($_SESSION);
        ?>
```

the session begins from my login script here:

```
<?
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    header("Location:home.php");
    exit;
}


    $dbh=new PDO('mysql:dbname=dashboardr;host=localhost', '******', '******');/*Change The Credentials to connect to database.*/
    $email=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];

    if(isset($_POST) && $email!='' && $password!=''){
        $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,password,psalt FROM user_login WHERE username=?");
        $sql->execute(array($email));

    while($r=$sql->fetch()){
        $p=$r['password'];
        $p_salt=$r['psalt'];
        $id=$r['id'];
    }

        $site_salt="subinsblogsalt"; /*Common Salt used for password storing on site. You can't change it. If you want to change it, change it when you register a user.*/
        $salted_hash = hash('sha256',$password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

    if($p==$salted_hash){
        $_SESSION['user']=$id;
  $_SESSION['username']=$email;

        header("Location:home.php");

    }else{
        echo "<h2>Username/Password is Incorrect.</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: you have the key `user` and `username` also the issue is where it is set - which you haven't shown

Comment: you need to complete the code for  username retrieval from the database

Comment: you have to confirm that where is your username set and in which key.? rest in header file first write session_start then your rest of the code. Also your query part is not completed also.

Comment: is username same as email?

Comment: no where do you set `$_SESSION['username']=$email;` you do set `$_SESSION['user']=$id;` so um you get what you code

Comment: @Dagon As an example where could i set this?

Comment: anywhere after `$email=$_POST['username'];`

Comment: I set $_SESSION['user']=$id; right after $_SESSION['user']=$id;  and tried to call in the username like so  <?php $user = $_SESSION['username']; echo "Welcome $user"; ?> but shows blank

Comment: `user` is not `username`. `id` is not `email`

Comment: `$_SESSION['username']` from your code, it should return an error about missing index!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason you do not see the user name in:

`$_SESSION['username']`

is because you never put it there.

you need to assign the user name to the session like so:

`$_SESSION['username']=$email;`

you can then `echo $_SESSION['username'];` where ever you want the username displayed.

make sure on any page you use sessions you have `session_start();` before any output.

Comment: No, in this case the script should returns error about invalid index! @Dagon

Comment: When I var_dump I get this array(2) { ["user"]=> string(1) "8" ["username"]=> NULL }

Comment: @sємsєм your making assumptions about error checking\level - many people code with them all off

Comment: @Dagon even if they make this error report off, it should not return number as the OP said, should not it?

Comment: @phpcoder update the code in the question with what you are currently using.

Comment: @Dagon Updated it now

Comment: your header page wipes out what you login page sets this: `$_SESSION['username']=$email;` should only be in the login page

Comment: so keep what I have done on the login page? What am I doing with the other pages?

Comment: the other pages `echo $_SESSION['username'];` where you want to

Comment: it returns it as a NULL value